# php jquery contact form without using mail()

Tags: php, contact-form

I've been trying to follow a tutorial to make a contact form - http://www.tutwow.com/htmlcss/create-a-simple-and-secure-contact-form-with-jquery-and-php/

The only problem is that it uses mail() which my host has disabled for 'security reasons'. I tried to make my own contact form a while back without fancy validation using smtp which worked fine, is there any easy way to use this tutorial example with smtp easily?

I'm quite clueless with php but I think I would need to change this from the tutorial:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

To something like:

```
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', 
        array ('host' => $host,
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password));

 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
```

Am I even close? Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are on the right path. You'd need to check the docs of the Mail class you are using, to ensure you are calling it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Most of PHP developers use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) if they want to ensure their script runs completely.
Try it out ...

Comment: thanks - found a tutorial using that http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/fancy-contact-form/ doesn't really explain using smtp though but giving it a try

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Zend_Mail_* classes. You can configure your SMTP very easily.

Setting up SMTP http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.sending.html

The documentation for the Zend_Mail class http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html

Alternative is SwitfMailer http://swiftmailer.org/